# Powershell script to find currently bound expiring certificates in IIS remotely

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, windows-scripting

I'm currently working on a script that will send an email once the certificates binded in my web servers' IIS are nearing there expiration date. I do have the script to send it in email. All I need to know is how to compare the certificates available in the store query versus the certificates currently in use. For now, here's what I have:

```
$Date= (Get-Date)
$SMTPServer = "smtp.test.com" 
$From = "testmail@noreply.com"

Import-Module WebAdministration

$Servers = @("WEBSERVER1", "WEBSERVER2")

$certificates = foreach($server in $Servers){
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { $CertAll = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My }
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { $CertInUse = Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\SslBindings }
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { $CertSame = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $CertAll -DifferenceObject $CertInUse -Property Thumbprint -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent }

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock { $cert = $CertSame | ForEach {Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My\$($_.thumbprint)} | 
  Select-Object Subject, DaysUntilExpired, NotAfter, @{n='ExpireInDays';e={($_.notafter - ($Date)).Days}}}
}

    $certificates | Sort DisplayName
```

Any help and suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script above never works as you are creating variables in separate sessions to the same computer.

You can do it in two ways.

1. Create a session object targeting the destination server once and reuse it. So that you will be able to get the variables defined in the session in subsequent `Invoke-command` executions.
2. Without creating a session object, but by executing everything on the remote server in a single `Invoke-Command` .

example:-

```
Invoke-command -computerName $Server {
    $CertAll = ....
    $CertInUse = ....
    $CertSame = ....
    $cert = $CertSame | ForEach ..... |
    Select-Object Subject, DaysUntilExpired .....

}
```

if you don't have any further actions on the remote server after identifying the certiricates expire date, I would suggest to use the second option.

Comment: @Didge added example

Comment: I get it now. Sorry for the confusion sir. But I think I can't access the `IIS:\SslBindings`. I always got the error that says `Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'IIS' does not exist.`

This is the the part, that I think, where I got the error:

`Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\SslBindings`

Comment: @Didge you need to Import 'WebAdministration' module prior accessing 'IIS:\'

Comment: @ PRASOON Yes, I do have that. Still, I'm still getting the error. Do I have to change something in the IIS? Also, I'm running the ISE as administrator. :(

Answer (score 0):

@PRASOON I already managed to check my certificates remotely. I try to work with different references I found in google. Anyhow, here's the script.

```
$Date = Get-Date
$servers = Get-Content C:\servers.txt

$cert = Foreach ($server in $servers) {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock{
        Import-Module WebAdministration; Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:SslBindings | ForEach-Object -Process{
            if ($_.Sites)
                {
                    $certificate = Get-ChildItem -Path CERT:LocalMachine\My |
                        Where-Object -Property Thumbprint -EQ -Value $_.Thumbprint

                    [PSCustomObject]@{
                        Sites = $_.Sites.Value
                        DnsNameList = $certificate.DnsNameList
                        NotAfter = $certificate.NotAfter
                        ExpireInDays = ($certificate.NotAfter - (Get-Date)).Days}
                }
            } 
        }
    } 

$cert | Select PSComputerName, DnsNameList, NotAfter, ExpireInDays | Where-Object {$_.ExpireInDays -lt 30} | Out-File C:\results.txt
```

So basically, this will display the certficates which will expire exactly or within 30 days from now. I am still working on this because what I'm trying to do is to send an email when the script detects a certificate that will expire 30 days from the current date and send an email notification. I will ask my concern about that in another post.